# (PHP) Initialize empty multidimensional array and then fill it

Tags: php, arrays, initialization, array-push

I want to create an array with 3 types of information: name, id, and work.
First I want to just initialize it, so that I can later fill it with data contained in variables.

I searched how to initialize a multidimensional array, and how to fill it, and that's what I came up with:

```
$other_matches_info_array = array(array());

$other_matches_name = "carmen";
$other_matches_id = 3;
$other_matches_work = "SON";

array_push($other_matches_info_array['name'], $other_matches_name);
array_push($other_matches_info_array['id'], $other_matches_id);
array_push($other_matches_info_array['work'], $other_matches_work);
```

This is what I get when I `print_r` the array:

```
Array
(
  [0] => Array
    (
    )
  [name] =>
)
```

What did I do wrong?

Comment: I assume that by copying the code you renamed the variables? Such as `$other_matches_name` and `$other_matches_nom`. Furthermore, I suggest you enable error reporting. This will help you debug your issue, as this code (as it is given) will return errors. The error should help you and if not, don't be afraid to ask for help!

Comment: I get a different result when I `print_r` the array. And some warning and notices.

Comment: If you want to use array_push try array_push($other_matches_info_array, array('name' => $other_matches_name, 'id' => $other_matches_id, 'work' => $other_matches_work));

Comment: You don’t need to “initialize” a multi-dimensional array as such. Initialize it as a simple array, nothing more. PHP will automatically create the necessary “dimensions” then you start assigning values, without any errors, notices or warnings. You should not be doing more than `$other_matches_info_array = array();` (or `$other_matches_info_array = [];`) as far as initialization of the variable goes.

Comment: @TomUdding Yes it was a mistake, thanks for pointing it out, I edited my message.

Comment: Thanks for the help @sochas and 04FS!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

very short answer:

```
$other_matches_info_array = array();
// or $other_matches_info_array = []; - it's "common" to init arrays like this in php

$other_matches_name = "carmen";
$other_matches_id = 3;
$other_matches_work = "SON";

$other_matches_info_array[] = [ 
    'id' => $other_matches_id,
    'name' => $other_matches_name
];
// so, this means: new element of $other_matches_info_array = new array that is declared like this.
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply create it like so:

```
$arrayMultiDim = [ 
    [
      'id' => 3,
      'name' => 'Carmen'
    ],
    [
      'id' => 4,
      'name' => 'Roberto'
    ]
];
```

Then later to add to just say:

```
$arrayMultiDim[] = ['id' => 5, 'name' => 'Juan'];
```

Comment: But what if I don't have anything to fill it with in the beginning? The variables I put in my example actually take their data from a database, so I want to initialize the array without content at first...

Comment: Declare empty array at the beginning of your code then fetch the records from DB and then by using for / foreach loop, you can create your multidimensional array.

Answer (score 0):

Try code below:

```
$other_matches_info_array_main = [];

$other_matches_name = "carmen";
$other_matches_id = 3;
$other_matches_work = "SON";

$other_matches_info_array['name'] = $other_matches_name;
$other_matches_info_array['id'] = $other_matches_id;
$other_matches_info_array['work'] = $other_matches_work;


$other_matches_info_array_main[] = $other_matches_info_array;
```

[Demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/864c866dd4a5dd98aad8047f379b4133ad040e4b)